# How to make sure that the reveal modal is closed in Zurb Foundation 4

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

In Foundation 3 one could easily make sure that a reveal modal was closed by using

```
$('#myModal').trigger('reveal:close');
```

If the modal was open, it would close. If it was already closed it would remain closed.

In Foundation 4 the equivalent is

```
$('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
```

Unfortunately, if the modal is already closed this will actually open it!

So, how do I make sure that the modal becomes closed in Foundation 4 (in JavaScript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have the same issue and I reported this bug to Zurb. The fix won't be available until version 4.0.9. Currently Foundation's download page allows you to download version 4.0.8. So if you need the fix now you can [get it from here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/414e1d78ffaa7e0f542fecc39218f921445aad0c/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js).

The issue was that when invoking the close method, they do a toggle on the open modal instead of just hiding it.

**UPDATE:** You can now download the latest code with the fix for this issue on [Foundation's main download page](http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php).

Comment: I'm having trouble returning control to the parent view when the modal is closed.  Perhaps you can help me.  My question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49161370/1735836

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle as Chris suggested, it will make it easier for us to help you.